# Accessing dataframe from variable name in xtabs

Tags: r

The problem is quite simple. I want to build crosstabs through the `xtabs` function. I also want to pass to the `xtabs` function the argument `data=` in the form of a string pulled out of a vector.

Consider the following MWE

```
dataframe_names <- c("DF1","DF2","DF3")
DF1 <- as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)
xtabs(Freq ~ Gender + Admit, data=DF1)
# Admit
# Gender   Admitted Rejected
# Male       1198     1493
# Female      557     1278
dataframe_names[1]
# [1] "DF1"
xtabs(Freq ~ Gender + Admit, data=dataframe_names[1])
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
#   invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
```

How should I pass the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `get`:

```
xtabs(Freq ~ Gender + Admit, data=get(dataframe_names[1]))
#         Admit
# Gender   Admitted Rejected
#   Male       1198     1493
#   Female      557     1278
```